# Lost the view and vob navigator

Tags: clearcase, remote-client

I created a working space to include one of my folders, and as soon as I clicked ok, now the ClearCase Navigator shows only that folder, and my vobs and views are gone from the GUI.
How can I bring them back?  I selected  Window -> Show View -> clear Case navigator, but the navigator only shows that one folder now, and I can't get it to show the vobs and views.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, by "working space" I meant "working set".

After some time trying to figure it out, I just went ahead and removed the "working set" I had created, and immediatelly my vobs and views came back to the ClearCase Navigator box.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be the intent behind working sets: see "[About working sets in the Rational ClearCase Navigator view](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/c_filters.htm)".

> Use working sets to limit the items that appear in the ClearCase Navigator view.
>
> It is possible to have a large number of nodes present in the ClearCase Navigator view. You may need to see only a small number of these nodes at one time.

As long as this working set is active, you cannot see other vobs/views.

> When a working set is turned on, the working set icon filtered ClearCase Tree icon appears in the left corner of the ClearCase Navigator tab and the name of the working set appears in parentheses on the right: (working set_name).